# Azure Data factory create file with file name have auto increase number

Tags: azure-data-factory, dataflow

I'm a newbie with Azure Data Factory, i want to create a file with this formnat:
File_Data_{AutoIncreaseNumber}.DAT. This file have a Auto increase number on that.
I have an idea about that, i create a file only contain number like this:

[image]

i want to get that value from that file, put it on filename on Data Flow. after that, update that file with value + 1.

but i don't know how to phut that value to File Name on Sink step. i tried with parameter but can't do it.
[image]

you guys please help! thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

A simple expression like this should do it in the file name property in the sink: 'myfilename-' + surrogate_key_column + '.dat'

Comment: it can't work with that, in sink step, i can't use any value from another steps to put on file name property

Comment: You need to switch the sink option from "Output to single file" to "Name file as column data". Use a Derived Column transformation just before your sink with the formula from my response above and call it something like myFileName. Then set the column in the sink to myFileName.